# Getting background crash with MainApplication.onCreate in react native android, any solution?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, crash, crashlytics

I am facing very strange issue in react native android build.

Facing this type of crash issue in latest uploaded build in play store, and actually I haven’t done anything if compare with previous version, I just change versionCode and versionName.

Also tried to google for “libfolly_futures.so”, but still not found any solution.

> MainApplication.onCreate

> java.io.IOException - could not delete: /data/user/0/<PACKAGE_NAME>/lib-0/libfolly_futures.so

[image]

[image]

[image]

And still this crashes are increasing every minute even if device is in background.

Thanks in advance, it would helpful for us if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with various approaches, I discovered a single remedy that proved effective.

Since the problem is associated with the SoLoader library, I attempted to upgrade it to version 0.10.4.

> implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.4+'

I also explored the option of updating the React Native version to 0.72.4.

I trust that this information will be beneficial to you.